# Как отрыть бинарный файл в Xamarin PCL?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile-development, filestream

Мне нужно создать Мобильное приложение, которое открывает бинарный файл и записывает данные в массив. Решил выбрать Xamarin для этого дела. Теперь не знаю, как открыть файл. Помогите, чем сможете или хотя бы подскажите в каком направлении копать.

Comment: вы бы хоть платформу указали, мобильное приложение - это слишком расплывчато. Ну а раз не указали - выбирайте сами https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/files/#Saving_and_Loading_Files

Comment: @rdorn Извините, но в вашей ссылке сказано, что можно считать только текстовый файл, а мне нужно бинарный формат. Подскажите, если я что-то не так понял, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: по ссылке приведен пример для текстового файла, но не "сказано, что можно считать только текстовый файл".

Answer (score 1):

Убелитесь, что используете правильный путь к файлу. Это будет частая ошибка, а в остальном можете использовать стандартный набор C#

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx

```
byte[] source = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToTheFile);
```

Тут общая информация по работе с файлами и папками в iOS:
https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/general/file_system/

Android:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/files/